# How do I generate a new set of values from existing dataset?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

This is a very broad question but I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

I have one big dataset and I need to generate some examples from it. The generated data should contain values that could have appeared in the original data set **(not random but values that still make some sense based on the original set)**. For instance:

```
Original Data Set

Vendor       |  Category      |  Problem Category      | Initial Detection Date | Action Date          | Affected Devices    |  Engineer | Type of Analysis | Priority

M-Operations |  Cybersecurity |  Bad security policies |   09/11/2017 12:00AM   |   09/11/2017 3:00AM  | Third party devices | John O.   | Hourly Analysis  | P1 
M-Operations |  Cybersecurity |  Penetration breach    |   09/11/2017 12:00AM   |   09/12/2017 3:00AM  | Third party devices | Samuel P. | Daily Analysis   | P2
Secure Total |  CERT          |  Bad security policies |   09/13/2017 12:00AM   |   09/13/2017 3:00AM  | Main frames         | Samuel P. | Hourly Analysis  | P1


New Data Set

Vendor       |  Category      |  Problem Category      | Initial Detection Date | Action Date          | Affected Devices    |  Engineer | Type of Analysis | Priority

M-Operations |  Cybersecurity |  Penetration breach    |   09/20/2017 12:00AM   |   09/21/2017 3:00AM  | Main frames    | John P.   | Hourly Analysis  | P1 
M-Operations |  CERT          |  Bad security policies |   09/23/2017 12:00AM   |   09/23/2017 3:00AM  | Mobile devices | Samuel P. | Daily Analysis   | P3
Secure Total |  CERT          |  Bad security policies |   09/29/2017 12:00AM   |   09/30/2017 3:00AM  | Main frames    | John P.   | Hourly Analysis  | P2
```

I found the following link [Generate data by using existing data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702979/generate-data-by-using-existing-dataset-as-the-base-dataset) that is similar to my problem but in that case all the values were numerical whereas in my example some of my values are non-numerical. If somebody could provide me an example of how to generate this new dataset in Python or R would be greatly appreciated for my inner peace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do this in R

```
# Create dataframe
original <- data.frame(Vendor = c("M-Operations", "M-Operations", "Secure Total"), 
                       Category = c("Cybersecurity", "CERT", "CERT"),
                       Problem = c("Bad", "Good", "Good"))

# Create a list of all unique values in each column
l <- list(
  Vendor <- unique(original$Vendor), 
  Category <- unique(original$Category), 
  Problem <- unique(original$Problem))

# Find all possible permutations
new.data <- do.call(expand.grid, l)

# assign names to the new dataset
names(new.data) <- c("Vendor", "Category", "Problem")
new.data
#         Vendor      Category Problem
# 1 M-Operations Cybersecurity     Bad
# 2 Secure Total Cybersecurity     Bad
# 3 M-Operations          CERT     Bad
# 4 Secure Total          CERT     Bad
# 5 M-Operations Cybersecurity    Good
# 6 Secure Total Cybersecurity    Good
# 7 M-Operations          CERT    Good
# 8 Secure Total          CERT    Good
```

After that you can subset this dataframe any way you want to leave as many records as needed for your test

Comment: So, we are doing all the possible combinations with list of unique values in each column but just wondering if there is any correlation on them.