# Python - Generating new larger dataset from existing dataset, looping row

Tags: python, loops

I looked at both [How do I generate a new set of values from existing dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206349/how-do-i-generate-a-new-set-of-values-from-existing-dataset) and [generate data by using existing dataset as the base dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702979/generate-data-by-using-existing-dataset-as-the-base-dataset) neither fullfill mig needs, so I read a ton off looping answers, but that didn't get me all the way.

I have the traditional adult dataset. After cleaning it and saving some for validation, so it look like this:

[Adult dataset - 43958 rows and 12 colums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAaVM.png)

I want to run a loop that takes each row and adds a new row where age is increased by 1, but keeps all other data equal to that of the row.

I have tried two diffrent ways.
Nr 1:

```
    df1 = newDataFrame

#iterate through each row of dataframe
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    new_row ={'age':index+1 , 'workclass':[], 'education':[], 'educational-num':[], 'marital-status':[],'occupation':[],
          'race':[], 'gender':[], 'capital-gain':[], 'capital-loss':[],'hours-per-week':[], 'income':[]}
print(new_row)
```

But that gives me:

```
 {'age': 35596, 'workclass': [], 'education': [], 'educational-num': [], 'marital-status': [], 'occupation': [], 'race': [], 'gender': [], 'capital-gain': [], 'capital-loss': [], 'hours-per-week': [], 'income': []}
```

I also tried:

```
df1 = newDataFrame
colums =list(df1)

#iterate through each row of dataframe
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    values = [([0]+1),[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11]]
    zipped =zip(colums, values)
    a_dictionary = dict(zipped)

    print(a_dictionary)
```

But get error

```
> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

I understand that it is becuase of the `colums = list` but I don't know how to change it. Tried some append() but that didn't help.

So after two days I turn to you.

To goal is to make the dataset bigger, but keeping a strong correlation between values.

Perfect, thanks @gofvonx!
I hade to make a sammal change but this worked

```
df1 = newDataFrame
df_new= df1.copy()
df_new.age += 1
pd.concat([df1, df_new], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above has some issues. E.g., `new_row` is overwritten at each iteration without storing the previous value.

But you do not need to use a loop. You can try

```
df_new = df1.copy()
df_new['age'] += 1
pd.concat([df1, df_new], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Note that `ignore_index=True` will create a new index `0,...,n-1` (see the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I hade to make a sammal change but df1 = newDataFrame
df_new= df1.copy()
df_new.age += 1
pd.concat([df1, df_new], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

Comment: @MetteH Glad it helped. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I would be glad to. How do I do that?

Comment: @MetteH There's a check mark to the left of the answer. You can also up-vote an answer. See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I had already voted it up (not visible because of newbi) but now also checkedmarked. Thanks again. 2 1/2 day of searching the internet is now ower LOL