# Generate a normally distributed data from a base data

Tags: r, excel, normal-distribution, data-generation

I have a data that somewhat looks like this:

```
Hit
77.77
55.55
100
44.44
```

I need to generate another set of data using elements from the data given above. The data should be normally distributed. Can I do that in excel?? If not, can I do that in r? Is there an R function that is specifically for this?
In case of R I used the suggestions from the following discussion:
[Generate data by using existing dataset as the base dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702979/generate-data-by-using-existing-dataset-as-the-base-dataset)
PS: this regards to the first answer and step two of the solution proposed. I did not removed the duplicates and I don't have missing values in my base data.

But the issue is that I am getting different values from what my data set has. Which is not the purpose I am l intend to pursue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. It sounds like you want to sample from the four values (thus avoiding "getting different values from what my data set has"). How do you reconcile that with "the data should be normally distributed"?

Comment: Agree with @JonSpring, please clarify. It sounds like what you want is impossible ...

Comment: @JonSpring It was just an example. I have data that contains 12 data observations. What I am trying to do is to create a database that samples observations from these 12 observations. The resulting data should be normally distributed with the N = 30. When I followed the solutions in the given discussion the resulting data set had values that were different from the observations I had in the base database. Essentially I am trying to do random sampling from the existing data set.

Answer (score 1):

See `sample()` for how to sample from a vector. For instance, `sample(Hit, 20, replace = T)` will give you a vector of length 30 by picking from your list. The data itself will not be "normally distributed", but a normal distribution might arise from it if you repeat an additive process based on that data.

For instance, given this vector:

```
Hit <- c(5, 10, 42, 2, 16, 19, 23, 4)
```

You can draw 30 samples with replacement, and plot a histogram. It's not a normal distribution.

```
set.seed(42)
Hit_30 <- sample(Hit, 30, replace = T)
Hit_30
# [1]  4  4 42 23 19 16 19 10 19 19  2 19  4 42  2  4  4  5  2 16  4 10  4  4  5 16  2  4  2 23
hist(Hit_30)
```

[image]

A normal distribution would emerge if we repeat an additive process based on this data. For instance, if we take the mean value of 30 samples, and then do that 10,000 times, the results are normally distributed:

```
Hit_30sums <- replicate(10000, mean(sample(Hit, 30, replace = T)))
hist(Hit_30sums)
```

[image]

Comment: so basically in order to produce a normally distributed data I need increase the sample size of the data?

Comment: No; if you draw a billion times from the original data, it will have the same values and distribution as the original data. It's through randomly adding samples from that data that a normal distribution would arise. For instance if you take the sum or the mean of a sample, and repeat that many times.